# How to edit the line style of a python pptx chart?

Tags: python-pptx

From the pptx documentation (http://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/charts.html), the code to create an XY chart is:

```
chart_data = XyChartData()

series_1 = chart_data.add_series('Model 1')
series_1.add_data_point(0.7, 2.7)
series_1.add_data_point(1.8, 3.2)
series_1.add_data_point(2.6, 0.8)

series_2 = chart_data.add_series('Model 2')
series_2.add_data_point(1.3, 3.7)
series_2.add_data_point(2.7, 2.3)
series_2.add_data_point(1.6, 1.8)

chart = slide.shapes.add_chart(
    XL_CHART_TYPE.XY_SCATTER, x, y, cx, cy, chart_data).chart
```

Anybody know how to change the series style to solid lines instead of markers?

Answer (score 1):

Use `XY_SCATTER_LINES_NO_MARKERS` instead of `XL_CHART_TYPE.XY_SCATTER`.